# Nginx https wildcard subdomains to https www

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to redirect `https://*.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` (`*` being any subdomain).

My Nginx configuration (unrelated lines removed):

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/vpsuser/example/example;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 http2 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

When I go to `https://s.example.com` no redirection happens and browser displays "this connections isn't secure". My code for same logic for http works without any problem.

And when I enter `https://example.com` it redirects to `https://www.example.com` successfully.

I tried `return 404` to see if it is really done by the same code block and I got 404 page. So, why it redirects `https://example.com` but not `https://*.example.com`? How can I solve it?

I am using Django. Just saying if there can be any relation.

Comment: Is the certificate valid for `s.example.com`?

Comment: @RichardSmith no it is not valid for it

Comment: The browser is refusing to negotiate a connection to the server because of the invalid certificate. You would need to create a wildcard certificate.